# Card DeckDriver java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I have fixed the problem, now it runs properly, my question is, what is wrong with my constructor? as someone pointed out there is a problem but i am not able to find it, also i want to extract and delete a card from my deck, any pointers on how to do such a thing?

My deck class:

```
 import java.util.*;


public class Deck {

    private static Card[] cards;
    private static int counter;

    int i=52;
    int x=0;

    public Deck(Card[] card){
this.cards=card;
    }



    public int createDeck(){

        cards = new Card[52];
        for (int a=0; a<=3; a++)
        {
            for (int b=0; b<=12; b++)
            {
                cards[x] = new Card(a,b);
                x++;
                counter++;
            }
        }

    }


    public Card[] resetDeck(){
        createDeck();
        return cards;
    }

    public static void getRandomCard(){
        int chosen = (int) (52*Math.random())+1;
        System.out.println(cards[chosen]);
    }

    public static int getCounter(){
        return counter;
    }

    public static void print(){

         for(int x=0;x<52;x++){
            System.out.println(Deck.cards[x]);
        }
    }


}
```

My DecktestDriver

```
public class DeckTestDriver {
    public static void main(String[] args){

        Deck test = new Deck(new Card[52]);
        test.createDeck();

        int input =test.getCounter();
        System.out.println("Number of cards in Deck = "+input);

        System.out.print("looking at one card in the deck-----");
        test.getRandomCard();
        System.out.println(".........................");

        System.out.println("Printing full list of cards in deck");
        System.out.println(".........................");

    test.print();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(".........................");
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("Creating New Deck");
    System.out.println(".........................");
    System.out.println();

    Deck test1 = new Deck(new Card[52]);
    test1.createDeck();
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("Printing new full list of cards in deck");
    System.out.println(".........................");

test1.print();
System.out.println(".........................");
System.out.println();

int input1 =test1.getCounter();
System.out.println("Number of cards in Deck = "+input1);

System.out.print("looking at one card in the deck-----");
test1.getRandomCard();
System.out.println(".........................");

    }
}
```

my card class:

```
public class Card {

    private int CardFaceValue;
    private int CardFaceSuit;
    private int cardFlippedNum;
    private int cardFlippedSuit;
    final static int MIN_VALUE_NUM=1;
    final static String MIN_VALUE_SUIT="Diamond";
    final static int MAX_VALUE_NUM=13;
    final static String MAX_VALUE_SUIT="Spade";



    public Card(int cardFlippedNum,int cardFlippedSuit){
        cardFlippedNumber();
        cardFlippedSuitType();

    }



    public int cardFlippedNumber(){
        int cFn = (int) (Math.random()*13)+1;
        cardFlippedNum = cFn;
        return CardFaceValue;

    }
    public int cardFlippedSuitType(){
        int cFs = (int)(Math.random()*4)+1;

        cardFlippedSuit = cFs;

        return CardFaceSuit;

    }



    public int getNum(){

        return cardFlippedNum;
    }

    public int getSuit(){
        return cardFlippedSuit;

    }

    public String toString() {      
        return (getCardName() + " of " + getSuitName());
    }

    public String getCardName() {
        switch (cardFlippedNum) {           //Change return cases to numbers if you want a number shown e.g: 1 of Hearts
        case 1:
            return ("Ace"); 
        case 2:
            return ("TWO");
        case 3:
            return ("THREE");
        case 4:
            return ("FOURTH");
        case 5:
            return ("FIVE");
        case 6:
            return ("SIX");
        case 7:
            return ("SEVEN");
        case 8:
            return ("EIGHT");
        case 9:
            return ("NINE");
        case 10:
            return ("TEN");
        case 11:
            return ("Jack");
        case 12:
            return ("Queen");
        case 13:
            return ("King");
        default:
            return ("" + cardFlippedNum);
        }
    }

    public String getSuitName() {
        switch (cardFlippedSuit) {
        case 1:
            return ("Diamonds");
        case 2:
            return ("Clubs");
        case 3:
            return ("Hearts");
        case 4:
            return ("Spades");
        default:
            return ("Invalid");
        }
    }



}
```

my output:

```
     Number of cards in Deck = 52
looking at one card in the deck-----Jack of Clubs
.........................
Printing full list of cards in deck
.........................
TWO of Spades
SIX of Clubs
NINE of Hearts
TWO of Diamonds
FOURTH of Clubs
FOURTH of Spades
TEN of Clubs
Jack of Spades
EIGHT of Diamonds
Queen of Diamonds
Queen of Diamonds
TEN of Spades
EIGHT of Hearts
Ace of Hearts
SIX of Diamonds
King of Clubs
THREE of Diamonds
TWO of Hearts
SIX of Spades
SIX of Hearts
THREE of Spades
EIGHT of Hearts
FIVE of Clubs
EIGHT of Diamonds
Jack of Clubs
Ace of Diamonds
NINE of Diamonds
SEVEN of Hearts
TEN of Diamonds
SEVEN of Diamonds
SEVEN of Diamonds
EIGHT of Hearts
FIVE of Hearts
THREE of Clubs
THREE of Spades
FIVE of Spades
TWO of Diamonds
TWO of Clubs
NINE of Hearts
FIVE of Hearts
SIX of Spades
TEN of Diamonds
FOURTH of Hearts
King of Hearts
Ace of Spades
THREE of Spades
NINE of Spades
King of Spades
King of Diamonds
King of Diamonds
Jack of Hearts
THREE of Clubs

.........................

Creating New Deck
.........................


Printing new full list of cards in deck
.........................
Ace of Clubs
SEVEN of Hearts
Queen of Clubs
TWO of Diamonds
King of Spades
Ace of Hearts
Ace of Spades
FOURTH of Spades
NINE of Spades
TWO of Hearts
FOURTH of Hearts
THREE of Hearts
THREE of Spades
Ace of Spades
Ace of Diamonds
Jack of Spades
TWO of Diamonds
Queen of Clubs
SIX of Hearts
TEN of Clubs
EIGHT of Diamonds
TWO of Spades
King of Hearts
TWO of Hearts
King of Hearts
NINE of Spades
FOURTH of Hearts
FIVE of Hearts
SIX of Clubs
Jack of Hearts
FOURTH of Spades
Queen of Clubs
TWO of Clubs
Ace of Clubs
NINE of Spades
TEN of Clubs
SIX of Spades
Jack of Spades
Queen of Spades
TWO of Diamonds
EIGHT of Spades
SIX of Hearts
Ace of Diamonds
FOURTH of Diamonds
Queen of Diamonds
Jack of Hearts
TWO of Clubs
FOURTH of Diamonds
SIX of Diamonds
King of Diamonds
TWO of Spades
TEN of Diamonds
.........................

Number of cards in Deck = 104
looking at one card in the deck-----SIX of Clubs
.........................
```

Answer (score 6):

After

```
Deck test = new Deck(new Card[52]);
```

You never called createDeck().  Your constructor and createDeck are somewhat schizophrenic, by the way.  You pass the deck into the constructor but you have no way to create a blank deck without creating a new array.

*edit*

1. Regarding the schizophrenia...

   For Deck's constructor, you have this:

   public Deck(Card[] card){
         this.cards=card;
      }

   What's strange is that I see a Deck as a collection of cards, yet you pass the cards into the Deck.  This may be just a matter of style.  However, I'd sooner expect:

   public Deck() {
        createDeck();
    }
2. createDeck() has a weirdness, by the way - it is supposed to return an `int` but has no return statement.  Perhaps a 'void' return in the signature would be better.  And I'd make it private.  If someone wants a new Deck, they should literally use `Deck deck = new Deck();`, not call `createDeck();`
3. I would never let Deck return the Cards[] array to the user.  The data structure and other internals within Deck are nobody's business.  `resetDeck()` does that.  Not returning Card[] implies that Deck would have to provide methods such as `Card getTopCard()` or `Card getRandomCard()` since it no longer 'opens the kimono'.  But that's a good thing - we want the Deck (a very nice noun) to have verb-ish methods that allow one to manipulate the deck.
4. I see a non-standard loop construct: `for (int b=0; b<=12; b++)`  This is *not* wrong.  However, generally speaking the conditional part of the loop is written without the <=.  Instead, a < is used.  So I'd expect `for(int b=0; b<13; b++)`   That being said, I ignore this semi-standard when the loop doesn't begin with zero.
5. In Card, I see `public String getCardName()`. consider a slightly different implementation.  The point is to remove lines of code (and hence bugs) by defining data structures instead of by writing explicit code.  See how the stringy switch statement is gone, having been replaced by a single line of *run-time* code.  The String array of cardNames is new but it's compile-time code and is unlikely to introduce an error.

> ```
> public class Card {
>     ...
>     private static final String[] cardName = new String[] {'ONE','TWO','THREE', ...etc};
>     ...
>     public String getCardName() {
>         return cardName[cardFlippedNum];
>         }
>
>     }
> ```

Comment: done, can you repeat your opinion on the constructor/createDeck again, i didn't understand

Comment: I added some pontification to my answer.  Feel free to ignore or ask more questions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create 52 cards with a loop first, I suggest doing these operations in Deck's constructor. Writing in pseudo:

```
public Deck() {
    cards = new Cards[52];
    for(i=0; i<52; i++) {
        cards[i] = new Card(i % 13, i / 13);
    }
}
```

After this Deck's card array will be like:

```
 {0,0}, {1,0}, {2,0}..{12,0}
 {0,1}, {1,1}, {2,1}..{12,1}
 {0,2}, {1,2}, {2,2}..{12,2}
 {0,3}, {1,3}, {2,3}..{12,3}
```

Comment: If we go this route, isn't it better to have String[] suits = new String[]{"spade","club","heart","diamond"} and then let `card[i] = new Card(i%13,suits[i%4])`?

Comment: Ah, I think your pseudocode is broken.  I don't believe the `i/13` bit is correct.  `i%4` instead would be more believable.

Comment: I was just giving an example here, assuming we construct Cards by Strings. Both %4 and %13 can be coded, it does no real difference. Editing according to the classes in the question.